# Summing variable by naming them with arrays as prefix

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

In the following code, I have several variables linked to a day of the week. I wish to regroup by sum all the values concerned by the same day (*eg. `sales_monday1` and `sales_monday2` sumed in a new variable named Monday*).
For this purpose, I thought to use an array :

```
    data test;
input sales_monday1 sales_monday2 sales_tuesday sales_wednesday;
datalines;
1 1 2 .
2 5 6 .
3 20 . 1
;
run;

Data test;
    ARRAY weekDays{*} Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday;
    set test;

    do i=1 to DIM(weekDays);
        weekDays{i}= sum(of sales_ weekDays[i]:);
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

My problem is : I cannot refer to my array in a sum function considering it is part of a concatenated variable name  `weekDays{i}= sum(of sales_ weekDays[i]:);`.
Does a solution to that matter exist?

Comment: If you have the option to change your data structure,  I suspect a long data format may be more useful. You can view some of the issues and benefits to this here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays don't quite work like that.  You're using them as if they're macro variables, when they're not.

You can't, thus, use the `:` suffix on the macro variable.  You can do this instead one of a few ways.

First, you could simply put all of the `sales` variables into an array, and loop over both, in whichever order you like, and compare variable names using `VNAME` and some help.

```
Data test_sum;
    ARRAY weekDays{*} Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday;
    set test;
    array sales sales_:;

    do i=1 to DIM(weekDays);
       do j = 1 to dim(sales);
         if upcase(compress(scan(vname(sales[j]),2,'_'),,'ka')) = upcase(vname(weekdays[i]))
            then weekdays[i] = sum(weekdays[i],sales[j]);
       end;
    end;
    drop i j;
run;
```

It's quite inefficient as you do a ton of unnecessary comparisons, so perhaps this isn't for you if you have a large dataset.  It's probably the right answer for a small dataset.

For a large dataset, you should do this with the macro language instead.

```
%macro sum_weekday(name=);
  %let weekday = %sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(scan(&name.,2,_)),,ka));
  &weekday. = sum(&weekday., &name.);
%mend sum_weekday;

proc sql;
  select cats('%sum_weekday(name=',name,')') into :sumlist separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where memname='TEST' and libname='WORK'
  ;
quit;

data test_macro;
   set test;
   &sumlist;
run;
```

This is pretty efficient as it only looks at the list of variables once, not once per row.  Basically, it just creates however many statements like

```
monday = sum(monday, sales_monday1);
monday = sum(monday, sales_monday2);
tuesday= sum(tuesday,sales_tuesday);
```

Etc., based on `dictionary.columns` which is the list of variables in all tables in your SAS.  (This may be slow if you're in a server environment with lots of libraries defined via the metadata server; you have other ways to do this, then.)

Answer (score 0):

Just write out the code. There are only 7 days in a week.

```
monday = sum(of sales_monday:);
tuesday = sum(of sales_tuesday:);
...
```